geopandas draw image from ncFile?
My Code is belowing :


import xarray as xr
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# notice : test_data is   xr.open_set("**.nc")
data = test_data
china_PRECT = data.PRECT  

# use geopandas to get map 
hebei_map = gpd.read_file('hebei.json')
hebei_geometry = hebei_map.geometry.unary_union

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    test_data.PRECT.mean(dim='time').values, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(test_data.longitude.values, test_data.latitude.values), crs="EPSG:4326"
)

Howerve upper is error:
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape.  Mismatch is between arg 0 with shape (156,) and arg 1 with shape (178,).
I print variable like this :
print(data.PRECT.mean(dim='time').values.shape)
print(test_data.longitude.shape)
print(test_data.latitude.shape)
print(test_data.longitude.attrs)

reusult :
(178, 156)
(156,)
(178,)
{'standard_name': 'longitude', 'long_name': 'longitude', 'units': 'degrees_east', 'axis': 'X'}
How I should do to solve it ?

The issue comes from your data being two-dimensional.
You have to flatten the arrays before creating your GeoDataFrame.
Using numpy's meshgrid can help doing so :
import numpy as np
import geopandas as gpd

longitude_2d, latitude2d = np.meshgrid(test_data.longitude.values, test_data.latitude.values)

prect_flat = test_data.PRECT.mean(dim='time').values.flatten()
longitude_flat = longitude_2d.flatten()
latitude_flat = latitude2d.flatten()

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame({
    "prect": prect_flat ,
    "geometry": gpd.points_from_xy(longitude_flat, latitude_flat)
}, crs="epsg:4326")

Hope it helps !
